# Laravel - ORM - call to undefined method

Tags: php, orm, laravel

`app/models/Model.php`:

```
<?php
    class Model extends Eloquent {    
        public function maker()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Maker', 'maker_id', 'id');
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to perform a search. The user enters the name of the model and the search should return the maker of that model (each model belongs to a certain maker). The following piece of code doesn't work:

```
$result = Model::where('title', 'LIKE', '%test%')->maker()->paginate(10);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::maker()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Appearantly "where" method returns object of type Builder and not Model

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any suggestions as to how to solve it?

Comment: Your modell is way too abstract, isn't it? Instead of `Model` it should be concrete table E.g. Maker. `Maker::where('.....')->paginate(10)`

Comment: Please read the question again. The user performs a search by entering the title of the model and the search returns the corresponding maker of that model.

Comment: It should be reversed, first make the object, then do `where` on it :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get what you're trying to tell me...

Comment: `Model->maker()::where('...')` I guess?

Comment: This is not valid php, it doesn't work.

Comment: of course it is not. Model should be the object of type model :) $model for example. Or, you need to make the maker static

Comment: See my own answer for the solution I came up with.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way.  Follow the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships and setup relationships between the Model and Maker models. That's a better solution than hard coding the joins as you do below.

Comment: The relationships are already set up. Could you provide any example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my own problem.

```
$result = Model::where('models.title', 'LIKE', $query)
->leftJoin('makers', 'models.maker_id', '=', 'makers.id')
->orWhere('makers.title', 'LIKE', $query)
->groupBy('makers.title')
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Why the duplicate `'models.title', 'LIKE', $query`?

Comment: One is `models.title` and the other is `makers.title`

Answer (score 0):

According to your solution:

```
// $search is the keyword to find
Model::with(['maker' => function ($q) use ($search) {
   $q->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%"); // where on makers table
}])->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%") // where on models table
    ->paginate(10);
```

This will return `Model`s that match `where` clause, with related `Maker`s, but only those who match the `where` clause too.

But what you need is probably this (according to your question):

```
Model::with('maker')->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%") // where on models table
    ->paginate(10);
```

This on the other hand returns the `Model`s that match the `where` clase, each with related `Maker`

*Note: namespace that `Model` class so it won't collide with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` (which it extends aliased as Eloquent)*